# How to clear a full IMAP mailbox using php_imap

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

I'm using **[PHP IMAP](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.imap.php)** and I want to remove all the mails in my box, but I can't find the way to select all folder.

I can retrieve all the folders names using `imap_listmailbox` :

```
<?php
    $folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.example.org:143}", "*");
?>
```

> **Yahoo for example :** return the following Folders names : (INBOX, Bulk Mail, Draft...)

And I can connect to all those folders and remove the `mails` inside using a loop, but not in the same time since I have to specify always the `FolderName` like example bellow :

```
<?php

    $mailBox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}FolderName", "username", "password");
    //__________________________________________^

    $mailsIds = imap_search($mailBox, 'ALL');

    foreach($mailsIds as $mailId)
        imap_delete($mailBox, $mailId);

    imap_expunge($mailBox);

?>
```

When I **Try** with no folder name, e.g :

```
$mailBox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}", "username", "password");
```

That select default folder `INBOX`.

When I **Try** with `ALL`, e.g :

```
$mailBox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}ALL", "username", "password");
```

That not return anything.

**NOTE :** In GMAIL I can found that they have a folder called `[Gmail]/Tous les messages` that contains all the mails.

Comment: Each folder is separate, and has to be dealt with separately.  In general, there's no way of viewing all folders at the same time.   Gmail is a special case of a server that has a SPECIAL All Mail folder, but that's not standard.